# Order of obtaining visas

Tags: visas

Let's say I am going to visit country A before visiting country B. Can I apply for the visa of country B before applying for the visa of country A?

Comment: Of course your can, why wouldn't you be able to?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can apply for the visas in reverse order, and if you are planning to visit them on the same trip, *you should do so*.

The reason for this is that Country A, in the middle of your itinerary, might not grant a visa unless they are satisfied that you can legally enter the country of your next destination, Country B. This is most commonly seen with Schengen states, though the UK and USA are also interested, as are other countries.

So therefore, you should already have the visa for Country B, at the end of your itinerary, in your passport before you apply for the visa for Country A.

Comment: How can country A know your eligiblity to enter country B? You might have dual nationlity amongst other reasons. Can you give references for this scenario?

Comment: @Berwyn They can look it up the same as anybody else.

Comment: They can look up whether you have dual nationality?

Comment: @Berwyn No, they can look up whether you need a visa to enter a country. If someone has dual nationality, it's their responsibility to provide that information to the consulate they're applying for a visa. In fact, it's even on the application (for UK, USA, Schengen, and many others). Remember that regardless of the country, the onus is on the visa applicant to show that he qualifies, whatever the rules for any given country are.

Comment: I mean a person is using passport X for country A and passport Y for country B. How can country A know that when they receive a visa application?

Comment: @Berwyn Again, because the visa application asked for that information!

Comment: Ok. I'll just admit I don't understand it

Comment: Schengen application form asks for permit and visa details for destination country when exiting Schengen zone where applicable. So, if my trip is India Netherlands Singapore on flight ticket, and by chance I have Indian and Singapore passports, its my responsibility that I provide my Singapore passport copy or details in the application. If i just provide Indian passport, they may/will ask how I am entering Singapore?

Comment: @Davinder Thank you for the explanation! I've applied for several visas and never been asked this. Guess it's mainly a Schengen thing?

Comment: @Berwyn US visa applications ask for all nationalities that you currently of have ever held. I suspect UK, Aus, Can etc all do the same.

Comment: @CMaster Ok. Well, obviously I don't pay much attention about this then!